# STM32 ADC to PWM

Tags: stm32, adc, pwm, cmsis

I have 4 ADC input channels and I want to convert the data (from potentiometer) to a timer 2 pwm output.

I have already configured the ADC and the PWM signals. Is there a way to check which adc channel triggered the interrupt?

```c
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{
  if(channel == 10)
  {
    TIM2->CCR1 = (int)((HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1) / 4092.0) * 100.0);
  }
  else if(channel == 11)
  {
    TIM2->CCR2 = (int)((HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1) / 4092.0) * 100.0);
  }
  ...
}

int main()
{
  ...
  TIM2->CCR1 = 50;  // set duty cycle channel 1
  TIM2->CCR2 = 50;  // set duty cycel channel 2 
  TIM2->CCR3 = 50;  // set duty cycel channel 3 
  TIM2->CCR4 = 50;  // set duty cycel channel 4
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1); // start pwm generation channel 1
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_2); // start pwm generation channel 2
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_3); // start pwm generation channel 3
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_4); // start pwm generation channel 4
 
  HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc1);
  HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc1);
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to differenciate the channels in the callback?

Comment: It's not really clear how you're configuring the ADC, but typically you'd configure a group of channels, and start the conversion (into a buffer that can hold all the sample values for each channel).. You get the interrupt when all the channels have been sampled. Then you'd update all of your PWM duty cycles. You wouldn't normally get an interrupt for each individual channel.

Comment: Aside: I'm not sure where your `4092` comes from. A 12-bit ADC will give values between 0 and `4095`. You can perform your calculation with integer arithmetic as `((HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1) * 100) / 4096)`. The division will be optimised into a bit shift, and you won't be using floating point arithmetic - which is often expensive and/or emulated in software on a microcontroller.